# Filter/scope by child records with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model `Service` with `has_and_belongs_to_many`relationship to a `Languages` model.

I would like to get a scope of all the services that have a given language.

I have tried 
    `Service.joins(:languages).where(:languages => Language.find(1))` but get `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'services.language_id'`as its using a 3rd table to create the association.

Now im stuck, any pointers please wonderful people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This must be the answer**

```
@language = Language.find_by_id(1)
@services = @language.services
```

Then run loop.

Comment: Brilliant, i was approaching it from the wrong way! Thank you!

Comment: Please approve this answer.

Comment: No problem, had to wait the 6 min time frame! Thanks